# Weird behaviour with UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, storyboard

I have a viewController with tablewView and 3 buttons under it. 
Looks like this

[image: Looks like this].

But when I press on the cell to see details and go back with navigation bar it looks like this

[image: it looks like this] (no buttons).

TableView.frame.x.y.width.height and all 3 icons.frame.x.y.width.height remain the same. Please share ideas about what it might be.

I've set AutoLayout with:

```
object.frame = CGrect()
```

Edited: 
my class with buttons: `homeButton, favouritButton, userProfileButton`

```
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    @IBOutlet var favouritButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var userProfileButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var homeButton: UIButton!
        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

            tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight - 49)
            let tabBarSegmention = screenWidth / 3
            homeButton.frame = CGRect(x: (tabBarSegmention / 2) - (homeButton.frame.width/2), y:  screenHeight - 6 - homeButton.frame.height, width: homeButton.frame.width, height: homeButton.frame.height)
            favouritButton.frame = CGRect(x: homeButton.frame.origin.x + tabBarSegmention, y:  screenHeight - 6 - homeButton.frame.height, width: homeButton.frame.width, height: homeButton.frame.height)
            userProfileButton.frame = CGRect(x: favouritButton.frame.origin.x + tabBarSegmention, y:  screenHeight - 6 - homeButton.frame.height, width: homeButton.frame.width, height: homeButton.frame.height)
        }
```

Comment: You should share the code that creates the buttons. Without it, I can only guess: Are these buttons local variables of your view controller? In this case they could be released when you show the detail view. If so, make them properties of your view controller so that they are retained.

Comment: edited fist post

Comment: Above you said "I've set AutoLayout with...". In the comment to my answer, you said instead "I dont use AutoLayout...". So my answer is irrelevant, and I will delete it.